# How do I get .bar file from momentics ide blackberry 10 cascades?

Tags: blackberry-10, momentics

I installed Momentics IDE for developing apps for Blackberry 10 cascades. How do I get .bar file from project? In my project structure I didn't get Bar package folder! And what is token?

Comment: please any one help him

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy your application to a device, you need to sign it. For that you need Signing keys, you can get them [here](https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/codesigning.html). Please read how to [Set up your environment](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/getting_started/setting_up.html), and more [about signing](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/dev/tools/signing_and_publishing.html).

If you can deploy application on the device just go in `Momentics File -> Export -> Release build`. Your .bar file will be in `\arm\o.le-v7`

Comment: thank you for reply. please tell me why my project structure not contain Bar packages folder?

Comment: You have to export for release if you want to get .bar file

Comment: In release build pop up i am getting " The destination folder does not exist. It will be created."

Comment: If you've changed location that's fine. Does it create it?

Comment: Sorry, i need to change which location? i am completely new to this

Comment: You don't need to change any locations. If you export it as release then it's been created. You only need to find it